# python: Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)

Tags: python, pyodbc, freetds

I am using python 2.7 for a specific job. I am connecting to MSSQL Server (2008) using FreeTDS. I can make some simple select queries but when I try to run a parametrised query I got an error:

```
('HY004', '[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Here is my query:

```
query = u"UPDATE table SET column1=? WHERE column2=?"
cursor.execute(query,[param1, param2])
```

However the same code on live works fine.

I have skimmed so many thread in various forums but they all seem misleading and I am really confused.

What is my actual problem and what do you suggest?

Edit: I've added query.

Comment: Please share the actual code, including the query you tried to execute.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thanks for your interest I've updated question with query.

Comment: What is in param1 and param2 ?

Comment: Oh sorry I was supposed to say that param1 unicode string (<type 'unicode'>), param2 is an integer.

Comment: It might be the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947077/using-pyodbc-on-linux-to-insert-unicode-or-utf-8-chars-in-a-nvarchar-mssql-field

Comment: @Faruk Sahin Thanks for you response however I already read that post  with no luck..

Comment: @huzeyfe Curious, what are the data types on `column1` and `column2` in SQL Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this is a super old thread, but I came across this same problem and the solution for me was to type cast the variables. For instance:

```
query = u"UPDATE table SET column1=? WHERE column2=?"

cursor.execute(query,[str(param1), str(param2)])
```

In this case it doesn't really matter what type the parameters are as it will be converted to a string.

Comment: This was *very* helpful

Comment: Funnily enough, here I am 2 years later and ran into the same issue and found my own answer.. Can't upvote myself though..

Comment: Have one from me then, wasn't my exact situation but led me to the answer (one of my proc's parameters is a table type that had a non-nullable column, to which I was passing a NULL in some records)