# Unable to execute a query in Python/Django which contains non-latin characters

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I try to execute a query in Python/Django, but eventually I end up with `ProgrammingError`. My script looks like this:

```
#--coding: utf-8
...
import pyodbc
...
def testquery(request):
    cnx = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=192.168.0.1;PORT=1433;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=sa;PWD=password;TDS_Version=7.0;ClientCharset=UTF8;")
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sys_Атрибут")
    ...
```

As you can see, the name of a table contains non-latin characters. If I instead query another table, whose name is in Latin, then it's ok.

I also tried this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ?",tablename)
```

And this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % tablename)
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: try `u"SELECT * FROM sys_Атрибут"`

Comment: It also has no effect

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: or maybe problem in your database backend

Comment: In database manager itself on the host machine I can execute such queries.

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals` does not help.

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals
cursor.execute(u'SELECT * FROM sys_Атрибут')`  if it does not help that problem in `pyodbc` == database backend

Comment: I've just red somewhere about `pymssql`. Some people say that this library has less problems with unicode characters. I will check it.

Comment: What problem can be in backend, if I can execute queries against "normal" tables with latin literals?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I will try to switch to `pymssql` and check if it helps.

Comment: `cursor.execute(u'SELECT * FROM sys_Атрибут'.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @madzohan Magic! It works! You can make an answer from it. I guess it will be useful for future programmers

Comment: ok) I've found detail info about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"FreeTDS handles Unicode for you" https://stackoverflow.com/a/964825/3033586

```
cursor.execute(u'SELECT * FROM sys_Атрибут'.encode('utf-8'))
```